# Manipulate processed numbers using siunitx

Tags: latex3

I am trying to manipulate numbers that are preprocessed, for instance, 1,000,000.50 to 1.000.000, getting rid of precision and replacing thousands separator with ','.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\removeComma}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { (\,) } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\num[round-precision=0, group-separator = {.}]]{\removeComma{1,000,000.00}}

\end{document}
```

However, I end up with an error

```
Package siunitx error: Invalid number '\removeComma{1,000,000.00}'
```

Comment: Yes, unexpandable commands generally cannot be nested inside other commands.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use `input-ignore` which `siunitx` already offers?

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  input-decimal-markers={.},
  input-ignore={,},
}

\begin{document}

% I've replaced "group-separator={.}" with "group-digits=none" because, well,
% having the group-separator equal to 'output-decimal-marker' is rather
% confusing.
\num[round-precision=0,group-digits=none]{1,000,000.00}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit** Considering the demands in the comments to have dot as group separator, comma as decimal marker, and "getting rid of the decimal", you could use:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  input-decimal-markers={.},
  input-ignore={,},
  output-decimal-marker={,},
  group-separator={.},
  % by "getting rid of the decimal", I presume you mean rounding.
  round-mode=places,
  round-precision=0,
  round-half=even
}

\begin{document}

\num{1,000,000.50}

\end{document}
```

With result:

[image]

I guess that, if you literally want to "get rid of the decimal" instead of proper rounding, you could use the `evaluate-expression` option. Either way, my general suggestion is that you use the flexible structure provided by `siunitx` instead of trying to parse the numbers yourself.

Comment: I want to convert a US number 1,000,000.50 to German number 1.000.000,50. Moreover, get rid of the decimal, the final result desired is 1.000.000

Comment: Well, I used your example... But you can use rounding options for the purpose, I'll edit in this direction.

Comment: Number with two separators like 1,000,000.50 fail to work with numprint, siunitx and ifnumless from etoolbox. All require either 1000000.50 or 1000000,50 to function. I tried to remove commas (the thousands separtor) ending up with 1000000.50 which fails to work too, probably as suggested due to it being nonexpandable.

Answer (score 1):

Experiment shows there are multiple steps, and with regex, the steps have to be done in the correct sequence (sometimes using a second tmp variable).

Break the task down into individual components, keeping them separated.

The experiment was to try various methods. Regex output versions are shown under (A):

[image: regex]

Regex is most compact: `\tl_remove` and `\tl_replace` and the `\str` equivalents are only partially useful here, though could be used (with more codelines and some logic of steps).

And looks like `si` is putting its own formatting in, too.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \removeCommaA } { o m }
 {
    TL ~ Regex ~ \IfValueT { #1 } { #1 }  \tex_par:D
    #2 $\mapsto$ 
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \.\d{2} } { } \l_tmpa_tl
    \IfValueF { #1 } { \tl_set_eq:NN \l_tmpb_tl \l_tmpa_tl }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \, } {  } \l_tmpa_tl
    \IfValueT { #1 } { \use:c { #1 } }
  { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl }
    \IfValueF { #1 } { 
                \regex_replace_all:nnN { \, } { \. } \l_tmpb_tl
                \tex_par:D >> ~ \tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl 
                }
 
 }
%\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\removeCommaB}{m}
% {
%  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
%  \regex_replace_all:nnN { (\,) } { } \l_tmpa_tl
%  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl 
% }
\NewDocumentCommand { \removeCommaC } { o m }
 {
    TL ~ Remove ~ \IfValueT { #1 } { #1 }  \tex_par:D
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
    \tl_remove_all:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { , }
    \IfValueT { #1 } { \use:c { #1 } }
  { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl }
 }
 
\NewDocumentCommand { \removeCommaD } { o m }
 {
        Str ~ Remove ~ \IfValueT { #1 } { #1 } \tex_par:D
  \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str { #2 }
    \str_remove_all:Nn \l_tmpa_str { , }
    \IfValueT { #1 } { \use:c { #1 } }
   { \str_use:N \l_tmpa_str }
 }
 
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

(A) \removeCommaA{1,000,000.00}

\removeCommaA[num]{1,000,000.00}

\removeCommaA[numprint]{1,000,000.00}
 
%(B) \num[round-precision=0, group-separator = {.}]{\removeCommaB{1,000,000.00}}

(C) \removeCommaC{1,000,000.00}

\removeCommaC[num]{1,000,000.00}

(D) \removeCommaD{1,000,000.00}

\removeCommaD[num]{1,000,000.00}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact that `\regex_replace_all:nnN` isn't expandable shouldn't prevent you from using its result in the argument of `\num` (or any other expansion-only context). You simply need to store the result in a macro and put that macro in the argument of `\num`. Indeed, performing *one expansion step* on a macro is an operation that, by definition, always works in expansion-only contexts!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% #1 must be a control sequence token
\NewDocumentCommand \removeComma { m m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn #1 {#2}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \, } { } #1
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\removeComma{\myresult}{1,000,000.50}%
\num[round-mode=places, round-precision=0, round-half=even, group-separator=.]%
  {\myresult}

\end{document}
```

[image]